# From TF-IDF to LDA clustering in spark, pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, tf-idf, lda

I am trying to cluster tweets stored in the format key,listofwords

My first step has been to extract TF-IDF values for the list of words using dataframe with

```
dbURL = "hdfs://pathtodir"  
file = sc.textFile(dbURL)
#Define data frame schema
fields = [StructField('key',StringType(),False),StructField('content',StringType(),False)]
schema = StructType(fields)
#Data in format <key>,<listofwords>
file_temp = file.map(lambda l : l.split(","))
file_df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(file_temp, schema)
#Extract TF-IDF From https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.2/ml-features.html
tokenizer = Tokenizer(inputCol='content', outputCol='words')
wordsData = tokenizer.transform(file_df)
hashingTF = HashingTF(inputCol='words',outputCol='rawFeatures',numFeatures=1000)
featurizedData = hashingTF.transform(wordsData)
idf = IDF(inputCol='rawFeatures',outputCol='features')
idfModel = idf.fit(featurizedData)
rescaled_data = idfModel.transform(featurizedData)
```

Following the suggestion from [Preparing data for LDA in spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33551407/preparing-data-for-lda-in-spark) I tried to reformat the output to what I expect to be an input to LDA, based on [this example](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-clustering.html#latent-dirichlet-allocation-lda), I started as:

```
indexer = StringIndexer(inputCol='key',outputCol='KeyIndex')
indexed_data = indexer.fit(rescaled_data).transform(rescaled_data).drop('key').drop('content').drop('words').drop('rawFeatures')
```

But now I do not manage to find a good way to turn my dataframe into the format proposed in previous example or in [this example](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.mllib.html#pyspark.mllib.clustering.LDA)

I would be very grateful if someone could point me to the correct place to look at or could correct me if my approach is wrong.

I supposed that extracting TF-IDS vectors from a series of documents and clustering them should be a fairly classical thing to do but I fail to find an easy way to do it.

Comment: Please mention your spark version

Answer (score 4, accepted):

LDA expect a (id, features) as an input so assuming that `KeyIndex` serves as an ID:

```
from pyspark.mllib.clustering import LDA

k = ... # number of clusters
corpus = indexed_data.select(col("KeyIndex").cast("long"), "features").map(list)
model = LDA.train(corpus, k=k)
```

Comment: Yes indeed, that is the issue I'd like to solve but casting the column appears to fail every time:
`input_c = input.withColumn("KeyIndex2" ,input['Index'].cast("int"))` and `input_c.take(1)` raises a time-out error  and I am pointed to _/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.pyc in read(self, size)_ **# fragmentation issues on many platforms.**
_   379                 try:
--> 380                     data = self._sock.recv(left)
    381                 except error, e:
    382                     if e.args[0] == EINTR:_
Isn't it the right way to cast a column ?

Comment: There is to much going on here. If simple data casting doesn't work there you have much serious problem. Please prepare a MCVE and ask it as a separate question.

Comment: I am facing the same issue, it is giving me this error `NameError: name 'col' is not defined`, my code is same as yours, how did you resolve?

Answer (score 0):

LDA does not take as input the TF-IDF matrix. Instead it only takes in the TF matrix. For example:

```
from pyspark.ml.feature import *
from pyspark.ml.feature import HashingTF, IDF, Tokenizer, CountVectorizer 
from pyspark.ml.feature import StopWordsRemover
from pyspark.ml.clustering import LDA

tokenizer = Tokenizer(inputCol="hashTagDocument", outputCol="words")

stopWordsRemover = StopWordsRemover(inputCol="words", outputCol="filtered", 
stopWords=stopwords)

vectorizer = CountVectorizer(inputCol="filtered", outputCol="features", 
vocabSize=40000, minDF=5) 

pipeline = Pipeline(stages=[tokenizer, stopWordsRemover, vectorizer, lda])
pipelineModel = pipeline.fit(corpus)

pipelineModel.stages
```

Comment: 1. LDA is not initialised. 2. stopwords - where did they come from. Please check na.